# how can i display/render 3D product files (http link) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, 3d

are there any plugins for flutter that can render/display 3D files?
I found this plugin: https://github.com/hemanthrajv/flutter_3d_obj
but seems like it will only work for local files but not network files.

Comment: Just clone the package and add an extra line to pass the contents as a String. You can see that in its `initState` it currently just loads a string either from an asset or a file. (Alternatively, download your content over http, save as a temporary file, and the use that.)

Comment: @RichardHeap thank you for the response :)  I will try the first method you suggested, as downloading all product images locally will not be ideal for 100+ products